# How to make a counter persist in Java?

Tags: java, jframe, counter, jlabel, dice

I'm making a dice game that scores points based on rolling a 7 or 11(pair of dice). The game keep track of the bets and score. The current score should be added to 3 times the bet amount if the the condition is met. However the score only changes the in the first instance the condition is met, then remain the same through any other roll attempts. I tried to set my getters and setters to be static but that didn't work. What can I do to make my counter work properly?

Program:

```
    public Game() {

            final Dice throwDice = new Dice();

            //Roll Dice
            rollDice.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    throwDice.PairOfDice();
                    diceResult.setText("You rolled: " + throwDice.getDie1() +
                                                " + " + throwDice.getDie2() +
                                                " = " + throwDice.getTotal());
                    currentScore.setText("Score: $" + throwDice.getScore());
                    if(throwDice.getTotal() == 7 || throwDice.getTotal() == 11) {
                        throwDice.setScore(Integer.parseInt(input.getText()) * 3);
                        currentScore.setText("Score: $" + throwDice.getScore());
                    } 
                }
            });
```

Comment: Where is input declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you say:

> The current score should be added to 3 times the bet amount

You are not adding to the current score. You are only setting the score to the 3 times the bet amount every time. So the value will not change (unless, of course, you change the bet amount).

```
 throwDice.setScore(Integer.parseInt(input.getText()) * 3)
```

Instead you need to add it to the current score:

```
 throwDice.setScore(throwDice.getScore() + Integer.parseInt(input.getText()) * 3)
```

Comment: thank you. You were right about my logic. I changed the code to this and it worked:
`throwDice.setScore((throwDice.getBet() * 3) + throwDice.getScore());
 currentScore.setText("Score: $" + throwDice.getScore());`

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of your Dice:

```
Dice throwDice = new Dice();
```

is in `actionPerformed()` which means it is created every time you call that function.

Move the declaration into `Game`, ie. make it an attribute of a game and you should be fine.

You can safely make `Dice::score`, `Dice::getScore()` and `Dice:setScore(int)` non-static.

UPDATE: Given there is still an issue, perhaps try replacing:

```
 throwDice.setScore(Integer.parseInt(input.getText()) * 3);
```

with:

```
 throwDice.setScore(throwDice.getScore() + (3 + throwDice.getBet()));
```

Comment: I moved it under 'public class Game extends JFrame {', however I'm getting the same results. The counter will only change once and remain the same.

Comment: this almost works. It performs the wrong calculation. I'm trying to multiply the current bet by 3. Your code multiplies my entire score by 3.

Comment: Oh, okay. Try:  `throwDice.setScore(throwDice.getScore() * Integer.parseInt(currentBet.getText()) * 3);`

Comment: Sorry no dice. The counter still changes one time only, which is after the condition is met. Then remains the same. I'm wondering if a while loop is necessary.

Comment: Oops. My previous comment was wrong. It was getting the value of a label. Try `Try: throwDice.setScore(throwDice.getScore() * Integer.parseInt(input.getText()) * 3);`

Comment: I would have thought that `actionPerformed()` is triggered every time you hit the *Bet* button. Can you check if that is the case in your debugger.

Comment: No luck. This time the score doesn't even computer. It remains at the default value.

Comment: You'll have to try stepping through with your debugger. Also be on the lookout for exceptions, eg. from `parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to move

```
Dice throwdice = new Dice`
```

up the code so that it is not called every time it enters actionperformed